# WCF Proxy + DI (Ninject) + IDisposable

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject

I have a MVC4 application that calls some WCF services.

I read about some problems that could happen when disposing WCF proxies with "using" syntax ([read this...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).
I am trying to implement WCF proxy disposal properly in my solution ([...and now this](http://web.archive.org/web/20100703123454/http://old.iserviceoriented.com/blog/post/Indisposable+-+WCF+Gotcha+1.aspx)).

A standard request runs through the following layers in the application:

**MVC Controller > "Main Facade" > "Minor Facades" > WCF proxies** (Legacy code. Not my fault)

I am using Ninject 3.2.2.0 to automatically inject the dependencies into these layers. For example:

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly SomeMainFacade _someMainFacade;

    public HomeController(SomeMainFacade someMainFacade)
    {
        _someMainFacade = someMainFacade;
    }
    ...
}
```

"Main Facade":

```
public class SomeMainFacade 
{
    private readonly MinorFacade1 _minorFacade1;
    private readonly MinorFacade2 _minorFacade2;

     public SomeMainFacade (
        MinorFacade1 minorFacade1,
        MinorFacade2 minorFacade2
       ){
             _minorFacade1 = minorFacade1;
             _minorFacade2= minorFacade2;
        }
        ...
 }
```

"Minor Facades"

```
public class MinorFacade1
{
    private readonly IWCFService _wcfServiceClient;

    public MinorFacade1(IWCFService wcfServiceClient)
    {
        _wcfServiceClient= wcfServiceClient;
    }
    ...
}
```

I'd like to dispose the WCF services used in the "minor facades" properly, but I cannot think of a way of this without a big refactoring. Maybe Ninject comes to the rescue...

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a class I wrote a long long time ago, in a galaxy far far away:

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public class RemotingClient<T> : IDisposable
{
    private bool _disposed;

    private readonly ChannelFactory<T> _factory;


    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public event OnCloseChannel ChannelClosed;

    public event OnFaultedChannel ChannelFaulted;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public delegate void OnCloseChannel();

    public delegate void OnFaultedChannel();

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="factory"></param>
    public RemotingClient(ChannelFactory<T> factory)
        : this(factory, SynchronizationContext.Current)
    {
    }

    private void OnClose(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (null != ChannelClosed)
            ChannelClosed();
    }

    private void OnFaulted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (null != ChannelFaulted)
            ChannelFaulted();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="factory"></param>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    public RemotingClient(ChannelFactory<T> factory, SynchronizationContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
        _factory = factory;
        CreateNewChannel();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="uiCallback"></param>
    public void PostToContext(SendOrPostCallback uiCallback)
    {

        Context.Post(uiCallback, null);
    }

    public void CreateNewChannel()
    {
        Channel = _factory.CreateChannel();

        ICommunicationObject c = Channel as ICommunicationObject;

        if (null == c)
            throw new ArgumentException(
                typeof(T) + " Can not be used as an ICommunicationObject");

        c.Closed += OnClose;
        c.Faulted += OnFaulted;
        c.Open();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public SynchronizationContext Context
    { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public T Channel
    { get; set; }

    public CommunicationState ChannelState
    {
        get
        {
            ICommunicationObject c = (ICommunicationObject)Channel;
            return c.State;
        }
    }

    #region IDisposable Members
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this._disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
                Close();

            this._disposed = true;
        }

    }

    public void Close()
    {
        ICommunicationObject c = Channel as ICommunicationObject;

        if (c.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
            c.Abort();

        c.Close();

    }

    #endregion
}
```

then basically you create a static ChannelFactory somewhere (I imagine this is what would be passed to your minorfacade) and then call RemotingClient. Like so:

```
public class MinorFacade1
{
    private static ChannelFactory<IMyServiceContract> MyFactory{ get; set; }

    public MinorFacade1(ChannelFactory<IMyServiceContract> factory)
    {
        MyFactory = factory;
     }


    public void DoSomeAwesomeWcfCall()
    {
       using(RemotingClient<IMyServiceContract> proxy = new RemotingClient<IMyServiceContract>(MyFactory)
            proxy.Channel.ThisIsAnAwesomeWcfCall();
     }
```

}